# How to set NsArraym to NSString in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, nsdictionary

I have been trying to set my json returned value to a string, but somehow it shows

```
 "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10ecdae00) to 'NSString' (0x10e2e6c60)."
```

i need this value

```
print(myBoard["marketing_refresult"] as Any)
```

in string. Check the below code`

```
func getData()
    {
        //fetch details
        let myUrl = URL(string:"http://kumbhkaran.co.in/iosAdmin/fill_survey_report.php")

        var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                   if error != nil{
                        print("error is\(String(describing: error))")
                    }
                    do{

                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]

                        if let parseJSON = json {

                            //var msg : String!

                            //getting json response

                            //let myBoard: NSArray = parseJSON["success"] as! [Any] as NSArray
                            let myBoard: NSDictionary = parseJSON["success"] as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject> as NSDictionary

                            print("--------------------------")
                            print(myBoard["marketing_refresult"] as Any)

                           self.markRef = (myBoard["marketing_refresult"] as Any as! String)//this line gives the warning for NSarraym to NSString conversion
                          print(self.markRef)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

     //return markref1
    }
```

Comment: You need to read about type casting in Swift because in several places you use it for no reason - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: What does "print(myBoard["marketing_refresult"] as Any)" print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **never** cast a good native type `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>` (aka `[String:AnyObject]`) to a bad typeless one `NSDictionary`. Don't use `NSDictionary / NSArray` in Swift at all. By the way a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3.

Just write

```
let myBoard = parseJSON["success"] as! [String:Any]
```

Second of all the error occurs because the value for key `marketing_refresult` is an array of dictionaries (rather than a string), you can use a repeat loop to iterate thru the array:

```
if let refResults = myBoard["marketing_refresult"] as? [[String:Any]] { 
    for result in refResults {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

To get all values for key `marketing_ref` as `[String]` write

```
if let refResults = myBoard["marketing_refresult"] as? [[String:String]] { 
    let valueArray = refResults.flatMap { $0["marketing_ref"] }
}
```

Please read the JSON carefully, it's very simple. There are only two collection types: array (`[]`) and dictionary (`{}`).

And – as always – `.mutableContainers` is meaningless in Swift, omit the `options` parameter.

PS: I doubt this URL requires a POST request.

Comment: thanx a ton ! Also what if i want to set reResults in a global String ? Is it possible to do this @vadian

Comment: Once again, `refResults` is an array (list) of dictionaries (key-value pairs). The values are many, many single strings. It depends on how you want to concatenate the strings.

Comment: Actually i wana print those refResults into a UIPickerView

Comment: I updated the answer to get the result as string array.